# Loop through PHP array with foreach and array_keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$texts` which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [CAR_SINGULAR] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [translations] => Array
                (
                    [de] => Auto
                    [en] => Car
                )
        )
    [CAR_PLURAL] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [translations] => Array
                (
                    [de] => Autos
                    [en] => cars
                )
        )
)
```

and then I have this piece of PHP code where I want to output the array with a simple `h1` and an `input` type text for each of the translation country codes.

```
foreach(array_keys($texts) as $text)
{ 
    echo "<h1>". $text ."</h1>";

    foreach($texts[$text] as $textData) 
    {  
        foreach(array_keys($textData) as $languageCode)
        {
            echo $languageCode .": <input type=\"text\" id=\"". $ID_OF_CODE_AND_TEXTID ."\" value=\"". $VALUE_OF_LANGUAGE_CODE ."\" /><br />";   
        }       
    } 
}
```

The result should be-

```
<h1>CAR_SINGULAR</h1>
de: <input type="text" id="de_1" value="Auto" /><br />
en: <input type="text" id="en_1" value="car" />

<h1>CAR_PLURAL</h1>
de: <input type="text" id="de_2" value="Autos" /><br />
en: <input type="text" id="en_2" value="cars" />
```

but somehow I am too blind to add the `id` and the `value` to the `input` :-(

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: `foreach(array_keys($textData) as $languageCode => $translation)`

Comment: I am sorry but this will give me: 0: <input type="..." value="de" /> 1: <input type="..." value="en" />

Comment: ah, it was correct. I had to adjust the output to: `echo $translation .": <input type=\"text\" value=\"". $textData[$translation] ."\" /><br />";`

Comment: @rwur  can you check my answer once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the html but this is the basic output:

```
$texts  = Array
(
    "CAR_SINGULAR" => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "translations" => Array
                (
                    "de" => "Auto",
                    "en" => "Car"
                )
        ),
    "CAR_PLURAL" => Array
        (
            "id" => 2,
            "translations" => Array
                (
                    "de" => "Autos",
                    "en" => "cars"
                )
        )
);

foreach($texts as $key => $subarr){
    echo $key. "\n";
    foreach($subarr["translations"] as $lang => $val){
        echo $lang . ": " . $val . "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

The Key of the first array is plural/singular.
Then I loop the inner subarray and output it's values in "translations".

https://3v4l.org/4AGmW

Comment: Ok, thanks but how to add the key in front of the input type and the id to the input? :-)

Comment: you mean language "de"/"en"? Added that to the code

Comment: `echo $lang .": <input type=\"text\" id=\"". $lang . "_". $subarr['id'] ."\" value=\"". $val ."\" /><br />";`